# How can i set background image for a button in windows mobile form?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am new to windows mobile. I need to set a background image for the BUTTON but i can see only the option to set background color. How can i set the background image.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17697) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446518.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example of what you are looking for

```
<Button x:Name="btnEventsS" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="93" Width="105" BorderThickness="0" Margin="-26,-10,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed" Click="btnEventsS_Click">
        <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/events-over.png" Stretch="None"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Bhavik Goyal, But i am developing a windows application.So, would you know how to take  a image in windows?

Comment: This is the code for Windows Phone 7. While adding the image to the folder, change the property of image to "add in resources".